# Watson Conversation and Google Map Static

Tags: watson-conversation

I'm currently giving google map static a long/lat for the location.
Is it possible to display the image of google map static on the conversation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to display it in the "Try it out" UI, but if you deploy your own application you can.

In your input node you can put the following line of text:

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=$long,$lat&zoom=11&size=200x200&sensor=false">
```

Then create a context variable `long` and `lat`. For example (placed in Welcome node).

```
{
  "context": {
    "lat": 55.27088,
    "long": 25.2048
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Hello. How can I help you?"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

Your previous line will be translated to this:

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=25.2048,55.27088&zoom=11&size=200x200&sensor=false">
```

Which will render:

[image]

---

The solution above will allow you to render in the conversation simple application.

Another option is to pass the lat/long as context variables to your application, and let it render. It will give you more control of how the map is rendered.

The following link will show what options you have for google maps.

https://developers.google.com/maps/web/

Comment: Thank you so much for a very detailed answer